# How to use file_get_contents safely?

Tags: php, security

I am making a basic PHP source viewer for my blog's example code folder.

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['file']))
{
    header('Content-type: text/plain');
    $filename = realpath($_GET['file']);
    if (startsWith($filename, dirname(__FILE__)))
    {
        echo file_get_contents($filename);
    }
}

function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    $length = strlen($needle);
    return (substr($haystack, 0, $length) === $needle);
}

?>
```

Is what I have here sufficient that it will never allow a file outside the directory in which this script is located, or subdirectories of this script's directory, to be viewed? I'm guessing there's a better solution than startsWith too, for checking whether a path is a descendant of a particular directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be safe, yes. The `realpath` part is what you have to do, and you are doing it. This code does what it's supposed to just fine.

Comment: But `realpath()` alone doesn't prevent from selecting another directory, so he still needs his `startsWith()` function to check, whether the requested file is inside the allowed directory. But all in all, the solution seems save.

Comment: @feeela: `realpath` obviously does not do anything like that -- it's not part of the function description. What I want to say is that the `startsWith` check is something everyone would think to do, but it's not safe *by itself*. It's the combination with `realpath` that makes it safe.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe reduce the input to a filename (see [finfo](http://php.net/manual/book.fileinfo.php)) and specify the directory to search in, if it's the same directory every time - so you don't need to check via `startsWith()`.

If you only want to show PHP-sourcecode, try to enable *.phps-file-handling within your webserver. See: https://serverfault.com/questions/62410/apache-htaccess-phps

Comment: Well, I can't reduce the input to just a filename, since I want to enable viewing of files within subdirectories of the base directory as well. As for the second part, I'm running IIS. ;)

Comment: @Jake Petroules "I'm running IIS" [Thats a bad excuse](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/753/enable-php-syntax-highlighting-on-iis-7/) :)

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, look into using [strncmp](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strncmp.php) instead of your custom startsWith function.

Answer (score 0):

If I was to approach a project like this I would:

Use a combination of your solution & htaccess to mask the original filename as having:

**http://example.com/viewsource.php?file=./project1/index.php**

would be just too obvious and tempting to mess around with, using htaccess you could have:

**http://example.com/source/project1/index.php**

that points too

**h1ddEnfIlEs/viewSource/index.php?file=$1&folder=$2**

```
RewriteRule ^source/([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+).php$ h1ddEnfIlEs/viewSourceScript/index.php?file=$2&project=$1
```

Then with the source viewer h1ddEnfIlEs/viewSourceScript/index.php

```
<?php 
if(
is_dir('./h1ddEnfIlEs/'.$_GET['project'].'/')===true && 
is_file('./h1ddEnfIlEs/'.$_GET['project'].'/'.basename($_GET['file']))
){
    highlight_file('./h1ddEnfIlEs/'.$_GET['project'].'/'.basename($_GET['file']));
}
?>
```