# How to URL Link to file outside root directory

Tags: php, upload

So i have a file uploader that allows people to upload files to the server and then download them via a URL.

I want to store uploaded files outside of the Root. (One level up from the root in a folder called Uploads)

Code snippet

```
$server = "http://www.mysite.com";

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

$destination = '../uploads/'. $random;
mkdir($destination);
move_uploaded_file($temp, $destination."/".$name);

$final = $server."/".$destination."/".$name;
```

This...

```
$destination = 'Uploads/' . $random ;
```

Didn't work (File not found error). ($random is defined by the way..)

Comment: Using the unfiltered `$name` will not guarantee the files stay outside of the docroot. Also why is the `Upload` directory uppercase in your second example, but not in the first?

Comment: You cannot hyperlink directly to files outside the docroot. You need PHP to read the file's contents via `file_get_contents()` or similar, and echo it to the browser, preceded by the correct `content-type` header based on the file's extension.

Comment: You can create a table on database with an IDENT (autoincrement) field. Then store filename on table and rename file to ident number assigned to row that store filename. I thing is the most elegant solution. You also can store type and size on row and inform to client navigator when user download file.

Comment: @Mario: The upper case is just an error in what i've pasted.

Comment: @Michael: Would it be right to do...

$yourfile = file_get_contents("/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/Upload/file.txt")

Then echo that out elsewhere?

Comment: @andre1990 Yes (with the filename on the end, not just the directory).  Call `header("Content-type: application/whatever"); echo $yourfile; exit();` substitute whatever MIME type is appropriate for the filetype of `$yourfile`.

Comment: @Michael didnt see your reply! Stupid site!

Would you agree with this?

http://pasteit.com/15757

Comment: Be very careful with you allow into the argument of `file_get_contents`. Malicious users could pass something like ../../../../../../../etc/passwd and retrieve the list of users on your server.

Comment: @andre1990 You're missing the actual download part. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6718494/how-to-use-file-get-contents-safely `file_get_contents()` is used to retrieve the file after it's been saved and then echo it out to the browser. This must happen after a `header()` call, and cannot happen if you are also outputting HTML on the page.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to make a symbolic link to ../Uploads in the web root:

```
ln -s ../uploads Uploads
```

Of course this makes the uploads directory web accessible. If you want to prevent the uploads directory from being web accessible, do not make the symlink, but instead add a rewrite rule that redirects requests to /Uploads/ to a php script that will pass the data through, perhaps only after checking for certain conditions (like if the user is logged in).