# How to upload to folder above root

Tags: php, file, upload

I want to upload to directory 'Uploads' which is one step above the root (using Plesk).

Could anyone tell me why the files won't upload there? Permissions have been give to Uploads as 777.

```
ob_start();

session_start();

$extensions = array("jpg", "png","jpeg", "gif", "zip", "rar", "swf", "tiff", "bmp", "txt", "fla", "7z", "tar", "gz", "iso", 

"dmg", "mp3", "wav", "m4a", "aac", "doc", "docx", "xls", "rtf", "ppt", "bsd", "exe", "psd", "c4d", "pdf", "dwg", "max", "ipa", 

"vtf", "iam", "ipt", "flv", "cap", "scr");
$maxsize = 104288000;
$server = "http://www.andre.com";

$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$temp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

$random = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$random = substr($random, 0, 20);

if (!$name || !$temp || !$size)
{
   echo "Go back and select a file.";
   exit();
}

foreach ($_FILES as $file)
{
 if ($file['tmp_name'] != null) 
 {
    $thisext1=explode(".", strtolower($file['name']));
    $thisext=$thisext1[count($thisext1)-1];
  if (!in_array($thisext, $extensions))
  {
    echo "That file type is not allowed.";
   exit(); 
  }
 }
}

if ($size > $maxsize)
{
   echo "File size too big.";
   exit();
}


$destination = "../Uploads/" . $random ;
mkdir($destination);
move_uploaded_file($temp, $destination."/".$name);

$final = $server."/".$destination."/".$name;
```

Looking at

```
 $destination = "../Uploads/" . $random ;
```

in particular which is found in `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/Uploads`.

Comment: What does it say in error log?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to URL Link to file outside root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862307/how-to-url-link-to-file-outside-root-directory)

Comment: @mephisto123 Where would i allow php errors?

Comment: well, not sure about virtual hostings, but on my own server it is enabled by default. Ask hosting support. Check FAQs. It is too hard to debug a script without error logs anyway.

Answer (score 1):

can be `open_basedir` or `safe_mode` restrictions, also check user privileges

Comment: open `<?php phpinfo() ?>` page and watch for [open_basedir](http://php.net/open_basedir) and [safe_mode](http://php.net/safe_mode)

Comment: Thanks, my open_base says:

/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/:/tmp/

And safe mode local value is off, master is on.

Comment: have you `error_reporting` set to `ALL` ? this might be useful for `move_uploaded_file` if it's not moving you file it might output some warning message

Comment: That is set to: 22527. This is all very confusing, spent a whole day just trying to move files up one directory! :(

Comment: set `error_reporting = E_ALL;` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` and try to upload your file one more time, try to catch some warning

Comment: Ok i will see how i can turn them on and report back as soon as possible.

Comment: OK Using Phoenix's first suggesttion the following errors occurred:


http://pasteit.com/15759

Comment: you can understand that by yourself, you can't store your file outside of your `open_basedir` so only in some dir inside of `/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs`

Comment: OK, im looking for a way to overcome that issue, i think it is possible.

Comment: I hope adding this to vhost.conf will solve:

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs>
        <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
                php_admin_flag safe_mode on
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/uploadvillage.com/Uploads:.:/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
        <IfModule mod_php5.c>
                php_admin_flag engine on
                php_admin_flag safe_mode on
                php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/site.com/Uploads:.:/php:/tmp"
        </IfModule>
</Directory>

What you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to upload from the root to Uploads, you don't use ../Uploads/ to reference that directory. It's either ./Uploads/, or just Uploads/.

../ references the directory above the current directory, which in your case would be /var/www/vhosts/.

Comment: I have tried

    $destination = "./Uploads/" . $random ;

And it still will not upload to that directory above the root. So i think my issue may be a combination of both answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try anchoring your relative path by using [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/_server):

```
$destination = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../Uploads/" . $random;
```

Alternatively, you can use a path relative to the current PHP script using [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/language.constants.predefined) (or `dirname(__FILE__)` if you are using PHP 5.2):

```
$destination = __DIR__ . "/../Uploads/" . $random;
```

Comment: This is all getting quite messy! My root is:

    /var/www/vhosts/example.com/Uploads

and my PHP upload script is in

    /var/www/uploadvillage.com/httpdocs/

So i should do:

$destination = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../Uploads/" . $random;

Answer (score 0):

I had a open_basedir error as user973... suggested.

Solved by creating vhost.conf in:

/var/www/vhosts/site.com/conf

Added in the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/>
php_admin_value open_basedir    "/var/www/vhosts/uploadvillage.com/httpdocs:/tmp:/var/www/vhosts/site.com/Uploads"
</Directory>
```

and then rebuilt apache config with:

```
[root@server1 ~]# /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
```