# Serving files from directory outside root

Tags: php, file

**Before** anyone says...not this leecher again... i solved my issue earlier and have to wait 6 hours to post my own answer, which i will be doing.

So i have files in:

```
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/Uploads
```

(One step above root)

How do i serve these files to people so they can download them? I'd like to provide a url or something?

```
$yourfile = ("/var/www/vhosts/site.com/Uploads/ . $random . $name. ")
```

Where `$random` and `$name` are defined elsewhere, then just echo `$yourfile` out?

Will that auto download the file when you click a link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to URL Link to file outside root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862307/how-to-url-link-to-file-outside-root-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Make the folder web-accessible
2. Make a symlink to this folder in your webroot.
3. Make a php script that get the file content and echoes it while putting the correct "content-type" before
4. Move your folder inside the webroot and create a symlink to that folder in the old location

Comment: Thanks Arto, i will alias the folder, but dont want to make it web accessible.

Also, is there a content type that will just prompt a user to download the file once it is called?

Comment: Mmm, actually, most of the content type are "downloadable". if you use application/octect-stream should be fine for make automatic download of your file :) (you will probably lose some browser depenent feature instead)

Answer (score 0):

You can echo something like:

```
<a href="Uploads/' . $yourfilepath . '">Click here to download</a>
```

Comment: The uploads directory is one step above the root. It is currently not web-accessible, so a link to the file would not work.

Comment: Ah, I assumed the OP meant one step below the root, because the Uploads folder is in the site.com/, not outside it.

Comment: It is accessible, one step above not below

Comment: Thanks for the answers, it is above the root yes.

Is making it web accessible the only way? Can't i just serve the file up on request?